# Is it possible to upgrade the NFTs to Ethereum Mainnet using Aurora’s Rainbow Bridge?

Tags: evm, nft, bridge

For instance, we want to build our Marketplace on the NEAR chain. In Ethereum we can achieve this by an arbitrary Message Bridge (AMB) to relay data between two EVM-based chains. With a classic NFT marketplace frontend, NFT artwork created and sold on xDAI using meta transactions, burner wallets, and bridged to Ethereum. And providing an optional upgrade feature that will upgrade the NFT to Ethereum Mainnet after paying the transaction fee with a real wallet and forwarded to Opensea. The users can also sell and buy the NFT in the side chain without upgrading to the Mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, though some connectors to move NFTs between Aurora and NEAR need to be implemented first. This can be implemented by someone from the community, it is not blocked on Aurora. After the NFT is in Aurora, with cross-chain bridge you can move NFTs between different EVM based chains, and with such a connector you can move the NFT from Aurora to NEAR.